# How do I get the coordination of each letter and also extract the letter in a numpy array?

Tags: python

I am making a project in the scrabble and I am wondering how can I extract the letter and the coordinates of the starting letter and its ending letter.

```
arr1 = [['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'E' 'A' 'G' 'L' 'E' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'P' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'P' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'L' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'E' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']]
```

I have the ouput of a scrabble game. How do I get its coordination of the starting letter in eagle also in apple and its ending letter. I also want to get the letter to form into words. In summary, I want to get the coordinates of all the letters in a word eagle.

Can someone help me with this, its been only a month since Im studying python. Thank you.

This is the orginal data.

```
k = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E', 'A', 'G', 'L', 'E', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'P', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'P', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'L', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

Comment: Please could you share expected output?

Comment: are you missing commas or is this how the board looks

Comment: The specific output is like example the order of the word would be 7,5 7,6 7,7 7,8 7,9 for eagle and 7,6 8,6 9,6 10,6 11,6 for apple

Comment: I am using a numpy array I made a list and resize it ino 15x15

Comment: in that case please edit this accordingly with all necessary commas included, you're missing a bunch of them

Comment: This is the output if I use a numpy array . There are no commas when I resize it into 15x15.

Comment: but does the original have commas, it's kind of an important detail

Comment: So share expected output, do you want it to be a dictionary? `{words:coordinates}`?

Comment: Yes please can you show me a  list and a dictionary on how to do it?

Comment: @aws_apprentice I use this code to convert it into 15x15 arr1 = np.array([k])
arr1 = arr1.reshape(15,15) the k which has commas turned into the ouput that you see. Idk why, im still learning python sorry.

Comment: Please share the values comma separated

Comment: What values? inside the k?

Comment: can you share the original data as opposed to this transformed input which makes it harder to work with, it's really not that hard to understand

Comment: I already edited the code above sorry for not truly understanding.

Comment: Can someone help pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given input

```
k = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
     '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
     '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
     '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
     '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
     '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
     '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
     '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E', 'A', 'G', 'L', 'E', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
     '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'P', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
     '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'P', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
     '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'L', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
     '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
     '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
     '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
     '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

The following codes solves the problem. The steps are:

1. You want to go through every position and see if it's a starting letter.
2. If it is, check across and down to see if there are words.
3. As you check, fill in the positions of the letters in those words

```
import numpy

my_board = numpy.array(k).reshape((15, 15))
out_dict = {}

for j in range(my_board.shape[1]):
    for i in range(my_board.shape[0]):
        if my_board[i][j] == '0':
            continue

        # across
        if j == 0 or my_board[i][j - 1] == '0':
            k, l = i, j
            word_across = ''
            word_across_pos = []
            while l < 15 and k < 15 and my_board[k][l] != '0':
                word_across += my_board[k][l]
                word_across_pos.append((k, l))
                l += 1

            if len(word_across) > 1:
                out_dict.setdefault(word_across, [])
                out_dict[word_across].append(word_across_pos)

        # down
        if i == 0 or my_board[i - 1][j] == '0':
            k, l = i, j
            word_down = ''
            word_down_pos = []
            while l < 15 and k < 15 and my_board[k][l] != '0':
                word_down += my_board[k][l]
                word_down_pos.append((k, l))
                k += 1

            if len(word_down) > 1:
                out_dict.setdefault(word_down, [])
                out_dict[word_down].append(word_down_pos)

print(out_dict)
```

This code prints

```
{'EAGLE': [[(7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9)]], 'APPLE': [[(7, 6), (8, 6), (9, 6), (10, 6), (11, 6)]]}
```

---

Using list:

```
import numpy

my_board = numpy.array(k).reshape((15, 15))
out_list = []

for j in range(my_board.shape[1]):
    for i in range(my_board.shape[0]):
        if my_board[i][j] == '0':
            continue

        # across
        if j == 0 or my_board[i][j - 1] == '0':
            k, l = i, j
            word_across = ''
            word_across_pos = []
            while l < 15 and k < 15 and my_board[k][l] != '0':
                word_across += my_board[k][l]
                word_across_pos.append((k, l))
                l += 1

            if len(word_across) > 1:
                out_list.append([word_across, word_across_pos])

        # down
        if i == 0 or my_board[i - 1][j] == '0':
            k, l = i, j
            word_down = ''
            word_down_pos = []
            while l < 15 and k < 15 and my_board[k][l] != '0':
                word_down += my_board[k][l]
                word_down_pos.append((k, l))
                k += 1

            if len(word_down) > 1:
                out_list.append([word_down, word_down_pos])

print(out_list)
```

Comment: @JamesWu Yes. Sorry, forgot to attach output. Updated above.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you!!

Comment: What does .shape[1] and .shape[0] do?

Comment: the array's dimension is 15x15. ".shape" gets that shape in the form (15, 15). So shape[0] is the number of rows and shape[1] is the number of columns.

Comment: Oh I see what about this part? my_board[i][j - 1] why is it -1 and on the column my_board[i - 1][j] what will happen if its onyl my_board[i][j]?

Comment: That checks the spot to the left and above the current letter. If the current letter is indeed a letter but there is nothing to the left or above, then this is a starting letter.

Comment: Hi, I have a problem it counts the words but for some reason, there are times that it cannot count two keys with the same word example eagle, eagle. Can you help me fix his problem?

Comment: @JamesWu Answer updated above. So you need a list to capture all the different occurrences for the same word. The `setdefault` function sets the default to a list but if the key is already in the dictionary, nothing is done. Once you have the list, you can add the different occurences of the same word.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I could do this using list so that I could get the same word. Using dict is amazing but I think list could go well.

Answer (score 0):

How about like this:

```
array([['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E', 'A', 'G', 'L', 'E', '0', '0', '0',
        '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'P', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'P', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'L', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '0', '0']], dtype='<U1')

def grid_mapper(grid, t=False):
    word = ''
    coords = []
    for idx, vals in enumerate(grid):
        if sum(map(str.isalpha, vals)) < 2:
            continue
        else:
            for i, v in enumerate(vals):
                if v.isalpha():
                    word += v
                    if not t:
                        coords.append((idx, i))
                    else:
                        coords.append((i, idx))
                else:
                    continue
    return word, coords

res = dict()
for g in [(a,), (a.T, True)]:
    w, c = grid_mapper(*g)
    res[w] = c

print(res)

{'EAGLE': [(7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9)],
 'APPLE': [(7, 6), (8, 6), (9, 6), (10, 6), (11, 6)]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I still dont yet understand how you do this. Would you mind explain some to me? Thank you.

Comment: which part do you not understand? you should take a few minutes to try and understand before giving up

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!! I'm still learning python and as you have helped me I'll do my best to be better at it.